# Cell locking based of value in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in excel: containing the following headers:

> (A) Date & time, (B) Condition,(C) Energy,(D) Calculated val.

I want to lock cell C and D if cell B contains "ISO" and if it doesn't contain "ISO" I want the c and D cell to be unlocked so I can manually input values in.

Cell C recalls a value in another tab/sheet in the same workbook , same for cell D.

I have tried using:

```
Dim rng As Range
With Worksheets("sheet2")
    For Each rng In .Range("B7:B10004")
        Select Case LCase(rng.Value2)
            Case "iso", "ISO"
                rng.Offset(0, 1).Locked = True
            Case "select"
                rng.Offset(0, 1).Locked = True
            Case Else
                'do nothing if not ISO,iso or select
        End Select
    Next rng
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting Range.locked itself doesnt lock cells unless you protect the worksheet
So add a new line to lock sheet using VBA  - ActiveSheet.Protect

refer docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect